# Inherit padding width without position absolute? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Not sure, but I am currently not able to figure out. I'm trying to center the inner div (blue transparent one) from the parent (with the red background) inside the background. As an example, they're technically in each other perfectly at the first example in the snippet.

At the second example however I've added `padding: 5px;` to both of them to the red and blue one. To the blue one because I wanted to inherit the width some how.

https://jsfiddle.net/L8enbcy3/

```css
.box-1-1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.box-1-2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #0000ffb0;
  position: relative;
}


.box1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.box2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #0000ffb0;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-1-1">
  <div class="box-1-2"></div>
</div>

<pre>
  
  
  
  
</pre>


<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying is to get "box2" centered into "box1" like example 1 but **with its padding**, so that's covered by blue. without having to position: absolute it, if possible. What I'm thinking I have to do is to create and invisibile box absolute it, "center it with `top: 0` and `left: 0` when the parent has `position: relative`. Then as I mentioned with it being absolute it would go to the corners of the parents padding too and then in the absolute box, I would create a relative one with `display: table` and put in all the content.

My question now though is, is there another way to do that?

Comment: I have reviewed your code and JSFiddle, but am struggling to understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you post an image that displays the final result you are looking to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a negative margin if you insist on keeping the padding in place.

```css
.box-1-1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.box-1-2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #0000ffb0;
  position: relative;
}


.box1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.box2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #0000ffb0;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-1-1">
  <div class="box-1-2"></div>
</div>

<pre>
  
  
  
  
</pre>


<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You know other solutions too? Or an improvement to this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59689489/11161500

Or a workaround if margin is not possible?

Comment: As great as this is it should at least feature other options.

Answer (score 3):

## Solution 1: `transform: translate()`

You could use `transform: translate()` with variables to achieve what you want, without weird margins (next solution). [Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) some MDN about translate().

```css
:root {
  --padding: 5px;
}

.box1 {
  height: 50px; 
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: var(--padding);
}

.box2 {
  height: calc(50px + var(--padding)*2);
  width: calc(50px + var(--padding)*2);
  background-color: #0000ffb0;
  transform: translate(calc(0px - var(--padding)), calc(0px - var(--padding)))
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the box is brought up and left with translate, and the height is lengthened by adding the needed padding to it. Thisachieves the desired cover effect.

## Solution 2: Positive padding, negative margin

You could also use positive paddings and negative margins. Info below code snippet.

```css
:root {
  --padding: 5px;
}

.box1 {
  height: 50px; 
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: var(--padding);
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.box2 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #0000ffb0;
  padding: var(--padding);
  margin: calc(0px - var(--padding));
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

What's happening here is following the CSS box model, found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) and [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp). We're simply pushing out with margin and sucking in with padding.

Then, as per request in the comments, --padding is a [CSS variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) that stores the amount of padding that you want.

Hope I helped!

Cheers, Bobbay

Comment: I've forgot to mention that I wanted to center it with its padding so that red is covered by blue.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want red to be completely coverd with blue?

Comment: Indeed, that's what I mean.

Comment: Gotcha, updated my answer. EDIT: Nevermind, I was beat to the race...

Comment: also has to use margin but I guess it's fine, I was wondering if there was an automatic way to add it, probably with javascript. Maybe with calc() in CSS.

Comment: Gotcha, used CSS variables and calc(). Just change --padding to whatever you want and it will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** example 2 illustrate your need. just remove `padding` from both boxes  and set`top: 0;` and 'left: 0' with `position: relative` on box 2. *I hope this is the required solution*

to center `box 2` you need to make its dimension less than `box 1`. consider the extra pixels added with padding. so the inner box width and height should be `10px` less than the outer box.
Example:

```css
.box1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.box2 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #0000ffb0;
  padding: 5px;
}


.box1-1 {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.box2-2 {
  position:relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #0000ffb0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="box1-1">
  <div class="box2-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've forgot to mention: "What I'm trying is to get "box2" centered into "box1" like example 1 but with its padding. "
I've edited that, I'm sorry.

Comment: @karl-police I have edited my answer. please revise it and find if it is working for you or not

Answer (score 0):

To center box2 within box1 without absolute position, you can use following css:

```
.box1 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Would have nearly worked, problem is yes it gets centered but on the left and right side red is not covered by blue.